# Cisco AnyConnect with certificates on Linux

Tags: linux, cisco-vpn-client, cisco-anyconnect

I have a work environment where I am allowed to use my workstation as I want, but I don't have any support for Linux. If anything doesn't work or is broken I have to fix it myself.

On Windows we use Cisco AnyConnect as a VPN with **certificates** so we can work from home. Is there a way to copy that certificate on Linux and use it with OpenConnect?

Answer (score 1):

OpenConnect supports certificate based authentication. These are probably the options you're looking for:

```
-c,--certificate=CERT

  Use SSL client certificate CERT which may be either a file name or, 
  if OpenConnect has been built with an appropriate version of GnuTLS, a PKCS#11 URL.

-k,--sslkey=KEY

  Use SSL private key KEY which may be either a file name or, if OpenConnect has been built with an appropriate version of GnuTLS, a PKCS#11 URL.
```

For more details, you can refer to the official manual:

http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/manual.html

Comment: The OpenConnect GUI already helped me with this issue. My main problem is extracting a certificate and key format that the OpenConnect accepts.

Answer (score 0):

openconnect --certificate=certificate.p12  servername

on CentOS 7 helped to connect using the VPN Certificate

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little more?